# Name attribute in the list of columns for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data frame as shown;

```
is_fraud|Domain_name|safe|fraud|Domain_count|fraud_prop
-------------------------------------------------------
  0     |  a8.net.  | 56 |  1  |     57     | 0.017
```

When I try to check the columns using the command,`df.columns`, we can see as

```
Index([u'Domain_name', u'safe', u'fraud', u'domain_count', u'fraud_prop'], dtype='object', name=u'is_fraud')
```

May I know why re we saying a Name attribute towards the end, which says 'is_fraud'. I am trying to get rid of it, but am not sure how to do that.Advice/help is appreciated.

Comment: Because your `df.columns` is a series. And a `pd.Series` has an attribute `name`.

Comment: Technically it's not a pandas Series, it's a pandas Index object, but the point still stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, to get rid of a `pd.Series` or `pd.Index` name, just set its attribute to `None`

```
series.name  = None
```

In your case,

```
df.columns.name = None
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you set the name of the index, with `df.columns.name=='is_fraud'` or something similar.

Do undo that, you can just change the name to `None`

```
df.columns.name=None
```